# Make div float right while keeping line breaks

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make the following pattern in HTML:

```
CellA        CellB
             CellC
CellD        CellE
             CellF
```

I'm trying to use a mixture of divs and spans to do this. I make **CellC** inside of a div since browsers always place line breaks before and after the div ([Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)). I also give this div the CSS property **float: right** so that it will appear to the right (like shown above). Making it float right is working, but I think by doing this I'm removing the default property of the div, which I believe is **display: block**, which puts in the line breaks. Even if I add this property in manually, it has no affect.

Here is the code I'm trying out ([Along with a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0eqtzn2/)):

**HTML**

```
<div>CellA
  <span class="floatRight">CellB</span>
</div>
<div class="both">
  CellC
</div>

<div>CellD
  <span class="floatRight">CellE</span>
</div>
<div class="both">
  CellF
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.floatRight { float:right;}
.both {float: right; display: block;}
```

**The code above will cause my output to look like this:**

```
CellA        CellB
CellD   CellECellC
             CellF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another solution to your problem, you can use flexbox to do this.
Try this:

**html:**

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">CellA</div>
  <div class="item">CellB</div>
  <div class="item">CellC</div>
  <div class="item">CellD</div>
  <div class="item">CellE</div>
  <div class="item">CellF</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j0eqtzn2/4/)</kbd>

But if you can't use flexbox, the @Jaspreet Singh answers its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add following style to both class

```
.both { 
    float: right; 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;  
    text-align: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML structure, then this approach will be easy for you:

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        Cell A
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>
            Cell B
        </div>
        <div>
            Cell C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        Cell D
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>
            Cell E
        </div>
        <div>
            Cell F
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.right {
    float: right;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j0eqtzn2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using float? If there is no "good" reason to use float, because float removes the element from the flow of the design.

Try using `display inline-block` instead.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>foo</title>
<style>
.left {
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #0ff;
}
.right {
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #f00;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<div class="left">CellA</div> <div class="right">CellB</div>
<div class="left"></div>      <div class="right">CellC</div>
<div class="left">CellD</div> <div class="right">CellE</div>
<div class="left"></div>      <div class="right">CellF</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use DL here instead of DIV then it will be easy for you. because it's look like title and description

Here is the demo

[check demo here][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/j0eqtzn2/6/
```